# Transfer Failing in Solidity Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, tokens, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I am calling the following function from a front-end on a Solidity smart contract, but it is not transferring the price and commission amounts properly with the call functions, although the ownership of the token is transferred correctly using the safeTransferFrom function. How can I transfer the amounts?

```
 function tokTransfer(address payable from, address to, uint256 tokenId, uint256 price, uint256 commission) payable external {
    
    (bool success, ) = from.call{value: price}('');
    require(success, "Transfer failed.");
    (success, ) = address(this).call{value: commission}('');
    require(success, "Transfer failed.");

    this.safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId);
 }
```

Thank you. J

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense `address(this).call{value: commission}` it is transfering `commission` to itself. If you have a receive or fallback function it should work in any case. Does the contract have a receive function?

Comment: Hi @Ismael. I could add one, but the issue is that the total amount sent is actually being transferred to the contract when executing the safeTransferFrom function, in exchange of the token ownership transfer. I would like to transfer the price to the seller (which has authorised the contract to sell his tokens) and only the commission to the contract (instead of the entire amount, as is the case now).

Comment: If `msg.value = price + commission` the transferring price to the seller should be enough, the comission is already in the contract. If the `commission` is included in the price you should transfer `price - commission` to the seller.

Comment: Thank you Ismael. I am first transferring all the ethers passed to the contract with "this.safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId)", and then passing from the contract to the seller the price of the NFT token using "seller.transfer(1 ether)", and this is working fine. My question is why didn't "(bool success, ) = seller.call{value: price}('')" worked? I thought hat this was the new recommended way of transferring ethers.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what are you trying to do. `safeTransferFrom` doesn't transfer any ether it transfer the tokenId. Just remember `<address>.transfer(amount)` is transfering `amount` ethers from the **contract** to `<address>`.

Comment: Thank you again Ismael. I understand that the main purpose of safeTransferFrom is to transfer the NFT token. However, it appears that since I am calling this function via "this", which corresponds to my contract (i.e. this.safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId)), where the "from" corresponds to the seller of the token that has previously authorised the said contract to sell his items on its behalf, that the ethers corresponding to the price sent by buyer while calling the function are actually being transferred to the contract in exchange of the token transfer.

Comment: No, `safeTransferFrom` doesn't handle ethers. The code `this.safeTransferFrom(seller, buyer, tokenId)` makes `this` transfers `tokenId` from `seller` to `buyer`. It requires previous approval from `seller` to `this`. The ether should be in the contract since `tokTransfer` is `payable`, the buyer send ethers to the contract with the call to `tokTransfer`. I'm assuming the contracts have standard ERC721 behavior. Also it is kind a little odd that `tokTransfer` is in the ERC721 I'd use a separate contract.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Ismael. Got it. tokTransfer is actually my function, which is called by the front-end, but which itself calls the standard openzeppelin safeTransferFrom function. I am calling a customised function since it is also performing other tasks. Isn't this how it should be done?

Comment: It should work. It is subjective matter. If you want to validate that the buyer had sent ethers use `require(msg.value >= price, "Not enough ether sent)`.